# How efficiently share complex and expensive objects between python files

Tags: python, performance, object, initialization, python-lru-cache

In my case, I initialize and use these (complex and expensive) object in file1, import them in file2 and use. It doesn't waste time create multiple obj in multiple functions accross two files, and works for me.

```
# utils.py
from fancy_module import Fancy_class
expensive_obj = Fancy_class()
def func1():
    expensive_obj.do_stuff()
```

```
# work.py
from utils import func1, expensive_obj
def work_func():
    expensive_obj.do_other_stuff()
```

However when I hand it over to my colleague to deploy, he points out it takes quite some time to do `expensive_obj = Fancy_class()` during import, and it causes troubles in the prod framework we are using (and I cannot change that). He asks to put it in a getter and use @lru_cache to avoid duplication.

```
# utils.py
from fancy_module import Fancy_class
@lru_cache
def get_expensive_obj(): 
    return Fancy_class()
def func1():
    expensive_obj = get_expensive_obj()
    expensive_obj.do_stuff()
```

```
# work.py
from utils import func1, get_expensive_obj
def work_func():
    expensive_obj = get_expensive_obj()
    expensive_obj.do_other_stuff()
```

Not knowing how exactly lru_cache work, I worry if it would really avoid duplicating `expensive_obj`. Plus I need to create a few like this `expensive_obj` in a few dozen or so functions similar to func1() and work_founc(). Kind of messy.

Is there other solutions that allow me to:

1. share objects between functions across files
2. and avoid expensive initialization during the importing time

Thanks!!

EDIT:
Thank you all for good suggestions (@chepner) and tips on caching (@ Munya Murape). I cannot resist the temptation of convenience using globals (and since these `expensive_obj` never change once created, like constants). Here is another option that I'd like to hear opinions:

- create a small file `expensive.py` that only contains these expensive objects.
- import expensive and initiate where they are needed

```
# expensive.py - shared objects only
from fancy_module import Fancy_class
expensive_obj = None
def init_expensive_obj(): 
    global expensive_obj
    expensive_obj = Fancy_class()
```

```py
# work.py
import expensive
if expensive.expensive_obj is None:
    expensive.init_expensive_obj()

def work_func():
    expensive.expensive_obj.do_other_stuff()
```

Comment: Creation of the object should be deferred until it is actually needed, not created immediately upon import. You don't actually need a full cache to do that; a simple global variable initialized to `None` and updated by `get_expensive_obj` if necessary would suffice.

Comment: It also seems like both `func1` and `work_func` should be accepting an argument, rather than relying on a global variable supplied by any module.

Comment: `lru_cache` works fine here, although, you should probably just use `cache`

Comment: All good suggestions on init and passing an argument. 
I opt to use globals initially was because that those objects don't change once created. Much like a constant. 
Glad that `lru_cache` and `cache` work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncertain about `@lru_cache` and only require a single instance of `Fancy_Class` then you could perform manual memoization using this method.

```py
class Fancy_Class:
    @(lambda _:_()) # invokes the outer-part of getInstance at run-time https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE
    def get_expensive_object():
        _expensive_object = None # do not touch
        @staticmethod
        def inner():
            """ returns a cached instance on Fancy_Class """
            nonlocal _expensive_object
            if (_expensive_object):
                return _expensive_object
            _expensive_object=Fancy_Class()
            return _expensive_object
        return inner
    ...
```

This achieves the same result as `get_expensive_object` in your example with the only diffence being that it is a manual implementation of a (pseudo) cache store with a single value in it. Additionally, I also recommend encapsulating the `get_expensive_object` method inside only `Fancy_Class` so it is explicitely clear that this function is related to `Fancy_Class` (and you don't have to worry about seperately importing the function).

If you plan on being able to pass arguments to the `getInstance` function in the future I would recommend using `cache` or `@lru_cache` decorators rather than manually creating a cache in the style I did ([imediated invoked functions expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like what I used in the above are something typically only seen in languages like JS).

## How `@cache` and `@lru_cache` work

(NOTE: I have included this section since you seem unsure about how `lru_cache` works)

`cache(typed=False)` caches every single call made to the function based on the arguments passed. If `typed` is set to `True` then it will cache arguments based on their hash and their type. `lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False)` is similar to `@cache` with the destinction that `cache` will only grow to a maximum size of `maxsize` items. Once the maxsize is hit, the items will be removed from the cache using the [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_recently_used_(LRU)) policy. If `maxsize` is set to `None` then `@lru_cache` behaves just like `@cache`.

Comment: Is there some advantage using this magic over just cache?

Comment: In the case on of just saving one thing to the cache, my method does actually have a mild performance advantage over regular caching due to the fact that there is no hashing involved. In the case of actual caching (where a dictionary is nessisary to keep track of everything) - no. I would actually recommend not using an immediately invoked function expression like I did as due to this pattern being very unconvectional/entirely unsupport in many programming languages - hence many programmer are unfamilar to it.

Comment: Thanks for the helping with caching. I might use custom caching in the future.